# Mysterious error in render() while trying to run React tutorial code

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting an unexpected error while trying to compile the code in O'Reilly's "Learning React" book (probably because the library has moved on since the book was published). Unfortunately, this particular error isn't making any sense to me at all, so I don't really know where to begin.

The error in my browser (I used `create-react-app` and `npm start` to test the code):

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 
'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["React"].createElement')

render
src/App.js:23

  20 | render() { 
  21 |   const { addColor } = this 
  22 |   const { colors } = this.state 
> 23 |   return ( 
     | ^  24 |     <div className = "app"> 
  25 |     <AddColorForm onNewColor = { addColor } /> 
  26 |     <ColorList colors = { colors } />
```

Here's what App.js looks like:

```
import { React,Component } from 'react' 
import { v4 } from 'uuid' 
import AddColorForm from './components/AddColorForm' 
import ColorList from './components/ColorList' 

class App extends Component { 
  constructor ( props ) { 
    super ( props ) 
    this.state = { 
      colors : [ ] 
    } 
    this.addColor = this.addColor.bind ( this ) 
  } 

  addColor ( title , color ) { 
    const colors = [ ...this.state.colors, { id : v4( ) , title , color , rating : 0 } ] 
    this.setState ( { colors } ) 
  } 

  render() { 
    const { addColor } = this 
    const { colors } = this.state 
    return ( 
      <div className = "app"> 
      <AddColorForm onNewColor = { addColor } /> 
      <ColorList colors = { colors } /> 
      </div> 
    )
  } 
}

export default App
```

These are the versions I have in package.json:

```
{
  "name": "addcolor",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3"
  },
```

Comment: Do you see the same error when you remove `AddColorForm` and `ColorList` for a sec?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes, removing those lines makes no difference

Comment: add the entry file code `index.js` usually

Comment: @EricHasselbring `index.js` is importing `App.js` in this case.

Comment: I would start debugging this by removing most of the code and adding this slowly one by one. Have just the render function returning a blank `<div>`, and see if that passes. And then slowly add things back and you should find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is imo in the first line:
Instead of:

```
import { React, Component } from 'react'
```

import React via:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

Comment: No difference, I'm afraid.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the way you have imported React is just not correct and that definitely will solve one problem. Could you provide your example via Code Sandbox?

Comment: I had to make an identical change in a different included file, which I'd forgotten was also importing `Component`. For some reason, the error was only showing up on `App.js`. Your fix worked, thanks!